# NSNotificationCenter RemoveObserver Not Always Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Normally I add my observers in `viewWillAppear` and remove them in `viewWillDisappear`.  In this case I need one of the observers to continue even after the view is gone so that it can finish some work.  In order to make sure that the observer is only added once with this view, I do the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                                   name:@"imageSaved"
                                                 object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(postMessageWithImage:)
                                                name:@"imageSaved"
                                              object:nil];


}
```

I have performed a search through the rest of the application to ensure that this observer is NOT registered anywhere else.  Unfortunately sometimes, but not all times and there is no consistent factor, the notification is fired twice.  I have also ensured with breakpoints and NSLog that the `postNotifcationName` is NOT called more than once.  I have not been able to reproduce on the iPhone as the problem seems confined to the iPad.

In further troubleshooting I have checked that the method is being called from the same thread (no reason it wouldn't be but just to check).  This problem DOES go away if I put the `removeObserver`in `viewWillDisappear`, however, again that is not how I need this to work.

Clearly this is a case where the observer for this is being registered twice but I cannot find a reason why that would be.  As you can see from the code, any time this observer is registered it is first removed.  My only other thought is whether `self` could get "corrupted" such that the `removeObserver`wouldn't function properly?

Comment: I have an update.  I put a breakpoint at the removeObserver line so that I can examine "self".  It turns out, when this issue occurs, that self differs from the previous addObserver.  So somehow, under some circumstance that isn't repeatable, self is changing.  How best to deal with that?

Comment: This is quite unsafe way of doing things. It appears that you've probably two living instances of the same class. You should always remove observer if you dont need it anymore, the dealloc method is the right place. Plus notice that notifications are send asynchronously

Comment: I agree something is odd here.  It is not clear what is going on with self and why this only happens on occasion and with no pattern.  I did solve the problem based on feedback elsewhere on this thread, but I should look into this self difference problem and why it would be occurring.

Comment: Notifications are NOT sent asynchronously. This is a common misconception.

Answer (score 2):

Add your observer when the view will show, and remove it when will disappear.

**ADD:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(postMessageWithImage:)
                                                name:@"imageSaved"
                                              object:nil];
}
```

**REMOVE:**

```
- (void)postMessageWithImage:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                                   name:@"imageSaved"
                                                 object:nil];
  // here do your job
}
```

This is perfectly valid and efficient.

Comment: I am not sure that you read my question.  I indicated that I need the observer to continue when the view goes away in order to finish a task.  I already indicated that doing it the way you describe will fix the issue but it then removes what I am trying to do to begin with.

Comment: Ok, so you can remove the observer in your selector `postMessageWithImage `, and you done. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Actually that won't fully work for my cause but you have set me on the path to solve this.  Indeed putting the remove in the postMessageWithImage is the right thing, but I also needed to move the addObserver to the method that kicks off this process to begin with.  Otherwise it would only work once and not again until view was loaded.  I tested this approach for quite a bit longer than I needed to prior for the issue to show.  It seems to be working correctly for both iPhone and iPad.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the observer in `viewWillAppear:`, try adding the observer you wish to persist when the view disappears in `viewDidLoad`. Then you can call your `removeObserver:name:object:` in your `dealloc` method

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  I find, using breakpoints, that the calls to viewDidLoad and dealloc are not always in balance.  When they aren't, the same issue occurs.  I should also mention that I am using a splitviewcontroller.

Comment: @C6Silver I've also encountered situations where the break point in dealloc doesn't really work. Try putting `NSLog`s into dealloc to see that it does get called.

Comment: Based on the behavior of the app and the calls were definitely not balanced regardless of the breakpoint or NSLog.  The other approach in this thread of which I commented on worked best for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something to be executed once, put it in the predicate of a `dispatch_once()` call, like

```
static dispatch_once_t lock;
dispatch_once(&lock, ^{
    // put your addObserver call here
});
```

Comment: This is a good approach as well although I needed to find a place to rmeove the observer.  I think the path I took in one the other answers was better for me, but again I think this approach is also workable.